# Map<String, String> not being mapped

Tags: javascript, java

The front end sends this json to my API

```
{  
  "parameters":{  
      "MAIL_BODY":"saffsa",
      "MAIL_FROM":"sffasafs",
      "MAIL_RECEIVED_DATE":"asfasf",
      "MAIL_SUBJECT":"asfafs",
      "MAIL_TO":"ssfafs"
   },
   "templateID":"9093",
   "deliveryChannel":"NONE"
}
```

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/previewDocument", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/pdf")
public byte[] previewDocument(@RequestBody Map<String, String> parameters, @RequestBody String templateID, @RequestBody String deliveryChannel) {
    // TODO
}
```

But i'm getting this on my backend logs

> 2019-02-22 10:34:55.068  WARN 9976 --- [nio-8083-exec-7]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String`
>   out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token 
>   at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 15] (through
>   reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["parameters"])]

I don't understand what is the issue. `parameters` seems to be a Map right? Can someone explain me why this does not work?

Comment: Not a Spring person, but your JSON content appears to be nested two levels deep.  This is probably the cause of the exception.  You need single level JSON which can be mapped to key value pairs.

Comment: remove "@RequestBody String templateID, @RequestBody String deliveryChannel" in your previewDocument method.

Comment: @SHAHAKASH I need those values as well. How do I get them then?

Comment: create a class with `Map<String, String> parameters; String templateId; String deliveryChannel` and then use that as the sole parameter annotated with `@RequestBody`

Comment: templateID and deliveryChannel stoted in paramaters

Comment: create an object like this:-
    public class MyObject {
        private Map<String,String> parameters;
        private String templateID;
        private String deliveryChannel;
    }
add Setters Getters

Answer (score 1):

replace `Map<String, String>` with `Map<String, Object>` and the parsing will succeed.
the inner object gets parsed into a `Map<String, String>` .
you will need to cast/interrogate the type of the value in the method body something like

```
if (parameters.get("parameters") instanceof Map) {
  Map<String, String> parametersMap = (Map<String, String>)parameters.get("parameters");
  String body = parametersMap.get("MAIL_BODY");
}
```